# Tabbed Navigation in AngularJS

Tags: navigation, angularjs

In AngularJS, how can I create a simple tabbed navigation (switching content as tab is clicked)?

HTML:

```
<ul class="tabbed-navi">
    <li class="active">
        <a href="#one">Nav One</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#two">Nav Two</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#three">Nav Three</a>
    </li>
</ul>

<div class="active">
    Content One
</div>
<div>
    Content Two
</div>
<div>
    Content Three
</div>
```

I am looking for a simple, beginner-friendly example, *not* "download these other things and then..."

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/vojtajina/vM4FY/

Comment: Great! Now how can I a.) show the first content by default (this works `<div ng:show="selected == 1 || !selected">` or is there a better solution?) and b.) highlight the currently selected nav-element?

Comment: Have a look at the tabs directive from http://angular-ui.github.com/bootstrap/

Comment: "I am looking for a simple, beginner-friendly example, not 'download these other things and then...'" ;)

Comment: If ui-bootstrap is not "beginner" enough than I'm afraid you're out of luck.

Comment: To set default tab on page load you can use `ng-init="selected=1"` directive: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngInit

Answer (score 2):

See the AngularJS home page, the "Create Components" section.  That sample app defines two directives: `pane` and `tabs`.

For some additional explanation about how this works, see ['this' vs $scope in AngularJS controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11605917/this-vs-scope-in-angularjs-controllers)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this...

```html
<ul class="tabbed-navi">
    <li class="active">
        <a href ng-click="option=1">Nav One</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href ng-click="option=2">Nav Two</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href ng-click="option=3">Nav Three</a>
    </li>
</ul>

<div ng-class="option==1? 'active':''">
    Content One
</div>
<div ng-class="option==2? 'active':''">
    Content Two
</div>
<div ng-class="option==3? 'active':''">
    Content Three
</div>
```